# Stop automatically a task (Viewflow, Django)

Tags: django, django-views, django-viewflow

I've splited the flow and assigned several tasks to different users. How can I:

1. stop all the tasks after a certain time?
2. collect the available responses?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a DateTimeField in your the Model that controls your flow and perform a check for it whenever a user tries to interact with your flow?

Comment: @JorgeMauro that way I cannot end the flow if no one answers

Answer (score 0):

### Verify the datetime your flow should ends inside the view

At least once you will have to acess some view in order to verify if the flow has or hasn't ended. There you could implements a piece of the snippet provided in the **views.py** bellow.

Using the **@property** tag in your model allows you to perform, among many other things, some validation on the fly and returns it whenever requested as if a model attribute.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/glossary/#term-property

Example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods

---

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Flow(models.Model):
    ends = models.DateTimeField

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return timezone.now() < self.ends
```

---

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def interact_with_flow(request, pk)
    if Flow.is_active:
        status = 'Flow Active'
    else:
        status = 'Flow Ended'
    return HttpResponse(request, status)
```

Comment: thank you, I can use that solution for a workaround. Do you know if there's a way to terminate a set of tasks in the **else** of **views.py**?